# create 3x3 matrix in simulink 2014b is missing

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink

Previously, in MATLAB simulink 2013a, I had defined a 3x3 matrix by giving nine members as input. Now, moving to vesrion 2014b, I cannot find such block hence Simulink cannot run previous model.

This is a link refering to the block:

http://au.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/create3x3matrix.html

You can see screen shots of my simulink library. How can I produce 3x3 matrix? Any replacement?

[image: math opr]

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Toolbox issue: As you can see from the documentation (which is already linked in the question), the 'Create 3x3 Matrix' block is from the Aerospace Blockset Toolbox. Judging from the screenshot it appears that you don't have this toolbox in your R2014b installation.

One possible workaround would be to use 3 'Vector Concatenate' blocks to create the rows of the matrix, and one more block to concatenate these rows to get the final matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this block by writing "create 3x3 matrix" instead of "create matrix".

Comment: It's not a function. It is a block. MATLAB functions are run far slower that built-in blocks. I cannot use constant block as matrix members need to change during simulation too.

Comment: it is a block  in aerospace blockset -> utilities-> math operations